# Get state of agent installed on azure VMs of a specific subscription

Tags: azure, powershell

I have a Powershell script that runs on each VM of a subscription and gets and outputs something like this.

Code:

```
# Set the subscription context
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId 'c0978b9d-b809-45f4-aa76-xxxxxxx'
 
# Get all the VMs in the subscription
$vms = Get-AzVM
 
$scriptPath = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\statescript.ps1"
$tempFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\temp.txt"
$outputFile = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\temp\result.txt"

# Set table header
$line1 = @"
"Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS"
"@

# Write table header
$line1 | Out-File -FilePath $outputFile

# Loop through each VM and run the script if it's a Windows VM
foreach ($vm in $vms) {
    
 
    # Check if the VM is running a Windows OS
    if ($vm.StorageProfile.OSDisk.OSType -eq "Windows") {
        # Run the VARIASUIT_CHECK_WINDOWS.ps1 script on the VM
        $scriptResult = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -VMName $vm.Name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $scriptPath
        $scriptResult | Out-File $tempFile
        $contentFromFile = Get-Content -Path $tempFile
        $line8 = $contentFromFile | Select-Object -Index 7
        $line8 | Out-File $outputFile -Append
        Remove-Item $tempFile

 
        Write-Host "Harmor state of $($vm.Name) has been saved to: $outputFile"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Skipping $($vm.Name) as it is not running a Windows OS."
    }
}
```

Output of $scriptResult:

```
Value[0]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdOut/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : "Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STA
TUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS"
"AZTEST-TSTAPP1P","KO","KO","KO","KO","KO"
Value[1]        : 
  Code          : ComponentStatus/StdErr/succeeded
  Level         : Info
  DisplayStatus : Provisioning succeeded
  Message       : 
Status          : Succeeded
Capacity        : 0
Count           : 0
```

```
Output of the script:"Server Name","GPO_HARMOR","BIOMEDIC_AGENT","EDWARD_STATUS","SENSOR_STATUS","SENTINEL_STATUS"
"AZTEST-TSTAPP1P","KO","KO","KO","KO","KO"
"AZTEST-TSTAPP2P","KO","KO","KO","KO","KO"
"AZTEST-TSTAPP3P","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK"
```

The problem is that sometimes the script outputs /n when I parse line 8.
I would like to parse the file to get this exact info:

```
"AZTEST-TSTAPP3P","OK","OK","OK","OK","OK"
```

----------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Instead of ```$scriptResult | Out-File $tempFile```, consider something like ```$scriptResult | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $tempFile``` - this will write structured json instead of a flat text file, which is much more suited to automated downstream processing. You can read the content back as an in-memory object with ```$data = Get-Content $tempfile -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json```.

Comment: It looks like the ```Message``` property contains a csv string, which you could then convert using ```$message = $data.Message | ConvertFrom-Csv``` to retrieve another in-memory object that holds the column values - e.g. ```$serverName = $messsage."Server Name"; $biomedic = $message.BIOMEDIC_AGENT``` etc

Comment: Could you elaborate the exact issue, do you want output as 
"OK","OK","OK","OK","OK" ?
or sometimes /n is appearing while executing the script?

Comment: Here is the script updated: [link](https://codeshare.io/8p91EE) 
Here is the content of temp.txt: [link](https://codeshare.io/bv9VxA)
Here is the content of test.txt: [link](https://codeshare.io/oQrenr)
I m blocked in getting the value of message, any help please? :)

Comment: @woodyboow please include statescript.ps1 and  result.txt file